# Cumulative Monthly Returns from Monthly discrete returns

Tags: r, price

I have the following sample price data.

```
sample_data <- data.frame(Date = c ("2017-01-31", "2017-02-28", "2017-03-31", 
                                    "2017-04-30", "2017-05-31", "2017-06-30"), 
                          stock = c("a", "a", "a","a", "a", "a"), 
                          Price = c(10, 11, 17, 12, 13, 14))
```

I am calculating the monthly returns via the code:

```
UKValue <- diff(sample_data$Price) * 100 / sample_data$Price[-length(sample_data$Price)]
```

Now is there a code to link the monthly returns so I can get a cumulative returns for every month?

Comment: What do you mean by cumulative returns?

Comment: It would be the compounding returns so say we had a monthly return of 10% and the next monthly return is 50%. The first cumulative return would be 10% but the second cumulative return would be ((1+10/100)*(1+50/100))-1)*100 which is 65%. If it help me question rephrased would be how to convert my monthly returns to compounding returns?

Comment: Try `cumprod(1 + UKValue/100) - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cumsum(UKValue)
```

Cheers

Comment: This is incorrect you cannot sum Monthly Returns and get cumulative Returns.